# Perl - Associative Array with index

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Ok, I'm new to Perl but I thins this question is for Perl Gurus only :)

I need a well explain example of how to store and keep control of data read from a file. 
 I want to store them using an Associative array with index and then use a for loop to go over the array and print it to the screen. 
 For example:

```
 my %array;

$array{$1} = [0]

foreach $array (sort values $array)
 print "$value";
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 2):

First, Perl refers to associative arrays as "hashes".  Here's a simple example of reading the lines of a file and storing them in a hash to print them in reverse order.  We use the line number `$.` of the file as the hash key and simply assign the line itself (`$_`) as the hash value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash_of_lines;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $hash_of_lines{$.} = $_;
}
for my $lineno ( sort { $b <=> $a } keys %hash_of_lines ) {
    printf "%3d %s\n", $lineno, $hash_of_lines{$lineno};
}
```

Comment: To be fair to him, Perl used to call hashes "associative arrays", but that was far too much typing, so we stopped when Perl 5 was released in 1994. These days, the term is a useful indicator of people who have learned Perl from horribly out of date resources :)

Comment: or who have learned to program in horribly out of date Perl-inspired languages.

Comment: Your code is virtually identical to using an array, except for arrays having a zero first index. So, I would mention this, instead of just suggesting a silly solution.

Comment: @TLP: I was attempting to answer the OP question: "I need a well explain example of how to store and keep control of data read from a file".  Hence, I gave an example, however contrived.

Comment: @JRFerguson People ask for all sorts of silly things they do not need and should not use, so I think its a good idea to point this out to them. (And btw, the "silly" part was in reference to the question, not your answer. Sorry, I just realized that was ambiguous.)

Answer (score 1):

Or even easier via the slurp method from [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aAll):

```
@lines = io('file.txt')->slurp;
```

If you are reading a larger file you will probably want to lock the file to prevent racing conditions and IO::All makes it really easy to lock files while you are working with them.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely do not want to use a hash (associative array is not a perl construct any longer) at all. What you are describing is using an array. Hashes are used for storing data connected with unique keys, arrays for serial data.

```
open my $fh, "<", $inputfile or die $!;
my @array = <$fh>;
print @array;  # will preserve the order of the lines from the file
```

Of course, if you want the data sorted, you can do that with `print sort @array`.

Now, if that had been done with a hash, you'd do something like:

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } <$fh>;
print sort keys %hash; # will not preserve order
```

And as you can see, the end result is only that you do not preserve the original order of the file, but instead *have to* sort it, or get a semi-random order. All the while, you're running the risk of overwriting keys, if you have identical lines. This is good for de-duping data, but not for true representation of file content.

You might think "But hey, what if I use another kind of key and store the line as the value?" Well, sure, you might take JRFerguson's advice and use a numerical index. But then you are using an array, just forsaking the natural benefits of using a proper array. You do not actually *gain* anything by doing this, only lose things.